# It's time there was a change to the [delta] tag (and not a small one, either)

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just reviewed a draft [tag wiki entry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9680382) for [delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delta), and rejected it because although it contained 3 URLs of some relevance to some interpretations of the term *'delta'*, that was all it contained; it did not contain any explanation of what 'delta' might be supposed to mean.

I also looked at the questions with the tag, and it does not appear that the 158 questions are consistent in their use of [delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delta) either with each other or with the interpretation that the wiki entry was wanting to promulgate.

I checked the 'top users' list; only two answerers have more than 1 question with the tag (and the maximum is 3 — hardly an overwhelming number of answers).  There have been no upvoted questions or answers in the last 30 days if the empty columns in the [user list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delta/topusers) is reliable.

---

Since I originally wrote the question, both the tag wiki and the [tag information](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delta/info) have been approved.  However, the information in the tag wiki and info does not reflect all the the questions that are tagged with [delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delta).

---

In the absence of a strong consensus (either in the questions tagged with [delta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delta) or from the discussion here), I think the tag should be burninated.

If there is an overwhelming use case that I couldn't make out from a casual perusal of the questions list, then there needs to be serious clean up of the questions where the tag is used.  Many of them need to lose the tag as they are not related to the current tag wiki and info.

A selection of question titles:

- How to calculate delta latitude and longitude for MapView component in React-Native?
- Solr 5.2.1 Delta Import Handler not working
- How to Patch using Delta with multiple primary keys in OData
- How to do delta extraction from GIT for patching?
- Eclipse program runs faster than after it is exported
- I want to calculate a moving difference for my dataset below.
- Usage of RemoteCache with DeltaAware and Delta interface infinispan
- How can I implement frame independent movement with selectable speed
- Decide the delta values for testing assertEqual for double in JUnit Java
- Cassandra delta/relative querying
- Optimize image sequence leaving delta only
- Solr: Properly qualifying PKs of records in delta import
- Mysql group by where delta between records X
- what is the difference between GDIFF and BSDIFF apart from the reduced patch size

Comment: *Need better triangulation on [delta]*